# Unable to resolve "./elements/Marker" - can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-svg

I have problem with my SVG Component. I think that I've did everything properly, but this after compiling I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve "./elements/Marker" from "node_modules\react-native-svg\src\ReactNativeSVG.ts"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Can somebody check code that I provided below and tell me what's wrong? I'm currently working on latest Expo SDK and react-native-svg package. Ohh one more important thing to say.. I've tested it in Expo-Snack and it worked!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Defs, RadialGradient, Stop, G, Use, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class SvgRadialBackground extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={[
                    StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
                    { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
                ]}>
                <Svg width={width} height={height}>
                    <Defs>
                        <RadialGradient
                            cx="50%"
                            cy="14%"
                            fx="50%"
                            fy="25%"
                            r="177%"
                            gradientTransform="matrix(0 .5 -1 0 .5 -0.146)"
                            id="prefix__b"
                        >
                            <Stop stopColor="#FFF" stopOpacity={0.5} offset="0%" />
                            <Stop stopColor="#003232" offset="100%" />
                        </RadialGradient>
                        <Path id="prefix__a" d="M0 0h375v667H0z" />
                    </Defs>
                    <G fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                        <Use fill="#244F77" xlinkHref="#prefix__a" />
                        <Use
                            fill="url(#prefix__b)"
                            style={{
                                mixBlendMode: 'soft-light',
                            }}
                            xlinkHref="#prefix__a"
                        />
                        <Use stroke="#979797" xlinkHref="#prefix__a" />
                    </G>
                </Svg>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: try deleting `node_modules` and running `npm i`/`yarn` again

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply, but unfortunately it didn't work. I have to dig deeper :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out.. This marker which cannot be resolved it's kinda new feature, they actually update package couple days ago. I've installed it using expo install.. and it didn't give me the latest version. Now I've updated it manually and it worked.

Comment: Can you please share details how did you update your configuration?

Comment: Sure @PiotrPonikowski , running "expo install react-native-svg" adds "react-native-svg": "~9.9.2" in my package.json. I've checked official documentation for this package which is available here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg and notice that actually the latest version is 9.11.1. 

I've manually changed entry in package.json to "react-native-svg": "~9.11.1" and ran "npm install" one more time. It solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up there @PatrykKrawczuk, that solved it for me too.

Comment: No problem @Nando. I'm glad that I can help